# Which fonts preinstalled on Linux are the same as that on Windows 7+?

Tags: windows, system-installation, fonts

Which fonts are common in default Linux and Windows installation?

Are there any? Do these operating systems share any identical fonts? Or all fonts are different and there are no common fonts in default?

Comment: Linux comes with fonts that are similar to Windows. You can download Windows fonts but they don't seem to render correctly on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

There are no common fonts. Some fonts may be similar, such as Courier and Courier New, but there are no exact matches.

Comment: Man, that's insane! Any link to prove your statement?

Comment: Nope. But why does it matter?

Comment: To assure others that your statement is not based on water, but supported be some valid proof that can everybody check if he is still skeptical.

Comment: It's based on the fact that Microsoft paid for those fonts and Linux distro makers didn't, and that Microsoft won't use F/L fonts. Hence, the intersection point of the Venn diagram is empty.